# Disable CUDA watchdog timer on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server running, with no X Windows. I want to disable the CUDA watchdog timer, so that I can run lengthy kernels. All answers on the matter refer to modifying Xconfig. I don't have X running, so this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question is for about a year ago. I don't know if the answer is still important to the OP, but just to answer it for other viewers: I think if you're not running X, watchdog timer is not even enabled for CUDA kernels. See [this link](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3029/~/using-cuda-and-x) for more info.